# Show that $a$ is the fourth power of an integer if:

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ is an integer and $b$ is a fourth power of an integer such that $ab$ is the fourth power of an integer, explain why $a$ is also a fourth power of an integer.

Show that $a$ is the fourth power of an integer if:
$$b^4$$
$$(ab)^4$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: What can you say about the exponents in the prime decomposition of a fourth power?

Comment: Would the prime decomposition of a fourth power be $p^4=p \cdot p \cdot p \cdot p$.

Comment: @Dmitri: Not necessarily: not all fourth powers are fourth powers of a prime. The prime decomposition of $6^4$ is $2^4\cdot3^4$. The prime decomposition of $12^4$ is $2^8\cdot3^4$.

Comment: I see.  How does this help me show that $a$ is to the fourth power?

Comment: @Dmitri: Can you yet answer the question in my hint? The answer is the key to showing that $a$ is a fourth power.

Comment: The exponents are a multiple of $4$?

Comment: @Dmitri: There you go. An integer is a fourth power if and only if the exponents in its prime factorization are all multiples of $4$. So if $ab$ and $b$ are both fourth powers, ...